# reading two column data with strings in python, and modify the one column

Tags: python, multiple-columns

I am new to python and this is my first question at stack exchange. Could you please help me with the following?

Suppose I have the following column data in a text file

```
red 0.01111
blue 0.96333
green 0.05112
```

I want to modify the second column data in to percentage. So that should show as

```
red 1.111 %
blue 96.333 %
green 5.112 %
```

Finally I want to store all these as just one variable 'a'

so when ever I return a, in a function, I will get this information.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your output is inconsistent. You dropped the leading zero in the red line but kept it in the green line.

Comment: Sorry, Tom! I have just edited it. I was giving just a simple example of my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use fileinput for this purpose

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(["a.txt"], inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    if line !='/n':
        pre,post=line.split()
        sys.stdout.write(pre+' '+str(float(post)*100)+' %\n')
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)

before
red 0.01111
blue 0.96333
green 0.05112

after
red 1.111 %
blue 96.333 %
green 5.112 %
```

Comment: Hi Sundar, Thanks for your great help. How to store the output in a variable, so that I can return it in a function later.